# JQuery - Increase value output for each 50 entered

Tags: jquery

I've got a simple text box which users enter a number into - this then update multiple elements on the page with a value.

At the moment they script will multiple the number entered by a set amount.

```
    $('input').keyup(function() {
        var v = $(this).val();
        v = isNaN(v)?'':v;
        $(this).val(v);
        $("#spot1 span").html(v * 100);
        $('#spot2 span').html(v * 200);
    });
```

HTML:

```
    <div><input id="number" name="number" type="text"><br /></div>

    <div id="spot1">Section 1:  <span></span><br /></div>
    <div id="spot2">Section 2:  <span></span><br /></div>
```

What I would like to do is have the output for section 2 based on only increasing in digest very times x is entered into the input box

Eg.  Less then 50 section 2 shows 1, and then every 50 entered it increases by 1. So, if the number 250 was entered, section 2 would actually show 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use division in-line, try this sample entering in '250'

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
        var v = $(this).val();
        v = isNaN(v)?'':v;
        $(this).val(v);
        $("#spot1 span").html(v);
        $('#spot2 span').html(Math.ceil((v * 4)/250));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input id="number" name="number" type="text"><br /></div>

    <div id="spot1">Section 1:  <span></span><br /></div>
    <div id="spot2">Section 2:  <span></span><br /></div>
```

Comment: ceil looks to be the best option to use for this example. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#spot2 span").html(Math.floor(v/50) + 1)
```

should do the trick, at least for positive values of x.

Comment: Put me on the right track and almost gets the answer i need.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydzv524k/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input').keyup(function() {
        var v = $(this).val();
        v = isNaN(v)?'':v;
        $(this).val(v);
        $("#spot1 span").html(v * 100);
        $('#spot2 span').html(Math.round(v/50));
    });
});
```